# Regex to extract function notation with nested functions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract function notation from a string in javascript (so I can't use lookbehind), here are some examples:

- f(2) should match **f(**
- f(10)g(8) should match **f(** and **g(**
- f(2+g(3)) should match **f(** and **g(**
- f(2+g(sqrt(10))) should match **f(** and **g(**
- f(g(2)) should match **f(** and **g(**

Right now I am using

```
/\b[a-z]\([^x]/g
```

because I don't want to match when it is a string of letters (such as sqrt) only when there is a single letter then a parentheses. The problem I am having is with the last one in the list (nested functions). ( is not part of the \b catches so it doesn't match.

My current plan is to add a space after every ( using something like

```
input = input.replace(/\([^\s]/g, '( ');
```

Which splits the nested function so that \b comes into play [becomes f( g( 3))] but before I started messing with the input string, I thought I would ask here if there was a better way to do it. Obviously regex is not something I am super strong with but I am trying to learn so an explanation with the answer would be appreciated (though I will take any pointers that I can google myself too! I am not entirely sure of what to search for here.)

Comment: why do you have the [^x] ?

Comment: `/\b[a-z]\(/g`Based on the rules does [this](https://regex101.com/r/xM6eK4/2) works ?

Comment: I am saving things like f(x) for definitions and shorthand for expressions. It means that I will never be able to have a function like x(x) but I am ok with that.

Comment: Another way: don't try to do it with a regex, and use a js parser to extract a graph of function calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that `[^x]` is a negated character class that still *matches*, *consumes* the symbol after `(` and it prevents overlapping matches. To make a check that the next character is not `x`, use a lookahead:

```
\b[a-z]\((?!x)
         ^^^^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL2eR5/1)

Perhaps, you want to fail a match only if a `x` is the only letter inside `f()` or `g()`:

```
\b[a-z]\((?!x\))
```

From [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

> **Negative lookahead** is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else. When explaining [character classes][4], **this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a `q` not followed by a `u`. Negative lookahead provides the solution: `q(?!u)`**. The negative lookahead construct is *the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point*.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense, I need to read up on consumption, I am obviously not processing it correctly.

Comment: Appreciate the link too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to remove [^x]:

```
"f(g(2))".match(/\b[a-z]\(/g)
// ["f(", "g("]
```